# How can this simple query take so long?

Tags: postgresql

```
=> SELECT * FROM "tags" WHERE ("kind" = 'View') ORDER BY "name";
Time: 278.318 ms
```

The tags table contains 358 rows.  All of them are views at the moment.

```
   Column    |           Type           |              Modifiers
-------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------
 id          | uuid                     | not null default uuid_generate_v4()
 name        | text                     | not null
 slug        | text                     | not null
 kind        | text                     | not null
 external_id | text                     |
 created_at  | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()
 updated_at  | timestamp with time zone |
 filter      | json                     |
Indexes:
    "tags_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "tags_kind_index" btree (kind)
    "tags_name_index" btree (name)
```

Analyze says:

```
                                                QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=9.29..9.47 rows=358 width=124) (actual time=0.654..0.696 rows=358 loops=1)
   Sort Key: name
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 75kB
   ->  Seq Scan on tags  (cost=0.00..6.25 rows=358 width=124) (actual time=0.006..0.108 rows=358 loops=1)
         Filter: (kind = 'View'::text)
 Total runtime: 0.756 ms
(6 rows)
```

Comment: Post the output of `explain analyze SELECT * FROM "tags" WHERE ("kind" = 'View') ORDER BY "name";`

Comment: `Total runtime: 0.756 ms` is too slow for you?

Comment: @joop isnt that the time taken to run the `explain` query

Comment: @DavidT as it contains actual time this is an EXPLAIN ANALYZE which does the whole query and often is actually a bit slower then running the query.

Comment: @Eelke ah ok thanks for clarifying, i just learnt something :)

Comment: @Neil, looks like most of your time is spent in network latency and transfer of the actual result data.

Comment: You're not running this remotely from a different continent, are you?

Comment: To follow up on @Eelke and my comments, how long does `SELECT 1` take?

Comment: Also: on an idle or newly started DBMS, the *first* query can take long, if both the catalogs and the actual tables have to be pulled in from (slow) disks into memory buffers. For VMs and network storage this can even be worse.

Comment: @joop I'd say that's it, a simple caching effect and possibly some slow storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you run `analyze tags`? It will update the table's statistics.

First if all the `kind` values are `'view'` then an index on that column is useless. The index will only be used if the column's [cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28SQL_statements%29) is high otherwise it is cheaper to do a sequential scan on the table.

Second with only 358 rows it is cheaper to do a sequential scan anyway.